# How can we implement caching with HttpClient in .net core 2.2

Tags: .net, .net-core

how to implement caching in .net core 2.2

```
'HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ReportUrl);
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync("PoDataMaintenanceErrRpt?Po_No=" + Po_No + "&jobCodeId=" + CMSSecurity.UserJobCodeId);
                responseTask.Wait();
                var result = responseTask.Result;'

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core we recommend the use of HttpClientFactory which is a new version that greatly optimizes the performance, I leave you a link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to use this object, it goes by injection of dependencies